# Want to customize zip file property in Android/ kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am creating zip file in android by code at run time and wanted to customized or add new property-value to zip file during the file creation or later.

I am able to create zip file by code but not able to customized or add new property value to zip file.

Example - Like when we create zip file there is some default property in key value format like Name, Type and Size, same as I wanted to add new property and value to zip file.

I have attached screenshot for get understating in detail.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEJ5y.jpg)